# Convert column into object in R

Tags: r

I wanna convert first column into object in R so if the input looks like:

```
#name of df - KPIF
    namePill KPIPill
1: pill_tech     0.3
2:  pill_EUX     0.2
3:  pill_Bus     0.3
```

the output should looks like:

```
#name of df - KPIF
           KPIPill
pill_tech    0.3
pill_EUX     0.2
pill_Bus     0.3
```

Anyone could help ?
Regards,
Aleksandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the data frame:

```
KPIF <- data.frame(namePill=c('pill_tech','pill_EUX','pill_Bus'),
                   KPIPill=c(0.3,0.2,0.3))
KPIF
```

Then apply the rownames:

```
> rownames(KPIF) <- KPIF[,'namePill']
> KPIF
           namePill KPIPill
pill_tech pill_tech     0.3
pill_EUX   pill_EUX     0.2
pill_Bus   pill_Bus     0.3
```

Then drop the unnecessary column, suggesting that your data frame is a larger one having more columns:

```
> KPIF <- KPIF[!(colnames(KPIF) %in% 'namePill')]
> KPIF
          KPIPill
pill_tech     0.3
pill_EUX      0.2
pill_Bus      0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just save the vector you want (the `KPIPill` column) in a new object and assign the other vector (`namePill`) as `names()` for the new object:

```
KPIF <- read.table(text = "    namePill KPIPill
1: pill_tech     0.3
                   2:  pill_EUX     0.2
                   3:  pill_Bus     0.3", header = TRUE)


KPIF_named <- KPIF$KPIPill
names(KPIF_named) <- KPIF$namePill

> KPIF_named
pill_tech  pill_EUX  pill_Bus 
      0.3       0.2       0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

use first `rownames()`and then you can just get rid off the first column:

I was assuming you made your df like this:

`df=as.data.frame(matrix(c('pill_tech','pill_EUX','pill_Bus',0.3,0.2,0.3),3,2))`

otherwise you can just convert it to a data frame with `as.data.frame(df)`

then assign the column namePill to `rownames()`

`rownames(df)=df$namePill`

and then you can get rid off the column namePill if it bothers you

`df=df[2]`